# A question about maximum theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

These days, I am learning maximum theorem. There are two statements about this theorem.

Wikipedia: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem)

Berge's book: *Topological Spaces: Including a Treatment of Multi-Valued Functions, Vector Spaces and Convexity*

If $\phi$ is a continuous numerical function in $Y$ and $\Gamma$ is a continuous mapping of $X$ into $Y$ such that, for each $x$, $\Gamma x \neq \varnothing$, then the numerical function $M$ defined by $M(x)=\max \{\phi(y) \mid y \in \Gamma x\}$ is continuous in $X$ and the mapping $\Phi$ defined by $\Phi x=\{y \mid y \in \Gamma x, \phi(y)=M(x)\}$ is a u.s.c. mapping of $X$ into $Y$.

My questions:

1. Is $f$ (Wikipedia) (or $\phi$ (Berge)) a univariate or multivariate function?
2. What is the difference between a compact-valued correspondence (C, Wikipedia) and a continuous mapping ($\Gamma$, Berge)?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by univariate? The parameter is taken from some topological space, so could be $\mathbb{R}^n$ for example.

Comment: I do not have my Berge nearby, but I believe they mean the same thing (Berge lsc. & usc.). I prefer to think of set valued functions.

Comment: @copper.hat, Sorry, I mean $f(X,\Theta)$ (Wikipedia) is a function of $X$ and $\Theta$ while $\phi(x)$ (Berge) seems a function with only $x$.

Comment: Well, the devil is in the details, but I would guess they are equivalent. You could let $\hat{x} = (x,\theta)$ and $\hat{C}(\theta) = \{ (x,\theta) | x \in C(\theta) \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Thanks a lot. If we treat $Y\leftarrow(X, Y)$ in Berge's statement, it will correspond to Wikipedia.